# Detecting which ImageView has has been tapped

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

So i have 4 vStacks, each containing 9 `ImageViews`. Each `ImageView` represents one Card, alpha 0 is default. When a Card is Detected (with `ARKit`), my code sets the `ImageView` to alpha 1 so the user can see that the card has been scanned.

Now: I want to implement that when the user clicks on one of the `ImageViews`, an alert should pop up asking the user if he is sure he wants to delete the scanned card. My problem is, I have no idea what the best practice is to get the information that the card has been tapped and how to delete it without hardcoding.

In `ViewDidLoad` i set the images into the ImageVies like This:

```
//This repeats for all 36 ImageViews
imgView1.image = UIImage(named: "Eichel_6")
imgView2.image = UIImage(named: "Eichel_7")
```

```
/*When a image is detected with ARKit, this is what happens. Basically
 *it pushes the corresponding reference name to an array called 
 * scannedCards, handles them, and removes them afterwards.
 * spielPoints = gamepoints/points, spielmodus = gamemode
 */

func updateLabel() {
        //print all cards in scanned cards
        for card in scannedCards {
            points += (DataController.shared.spielpoints[DataController.shared.spielmodus!]![card]! * DataController.shared.multCalculator[DataController.shared.spielmodus!]!)
        }
        scannedCards.removeAll()
    }
```

I am a new to coding, I would be grateful if you correct me if my code snippets are bad, beside my question. Thank you in advance.

[image: My 4 vStacks with the ImageViews]

Comment: You can set a unique `tag` for each of them.

Comment: @SavcaMarin `tag` is never the way to go. It is a very bad pattern. And there is always a much more elegant solution. See number 2 here... http://benford.me/blog/12-dos-and-donts-for-ios-development/

Comment: Why not use a UICollectionView? You will save yourself a lot of time and avoid a lot of pain.

Comment: @Fogmeister using 36 image views instead of a `collectionView` is not the way to go, have all your app in a single `storyboard` is not the way to go. `tag` is a workaround if this is the way he wants to go.

Comment: @Starsky yeah, that was my thought too, after writing the answer below. LOL!

Comment: @SavcaMarin then write an answer that suggests to use a collection view if you think that's a better solution. Offering a "workaround" that you already know is a bad idea is not how StackOverflow works.

Comment: @Fogmeister thanks for inserting the Image, as it is my first post and i have no rep, i cant post them like that. If it would help, i can post some more screenshots or code snippets of my app.

Comment: @ilija.trkulja it would be useful to add the code that you are using to put the images into the image views.

Comment: I’ll add an answer later that will show how to use UICollectionView for this. You could also possibly have a read up on this yourself too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been mentioned in comments, you should use a `UICollectionView` for this kind of work. @Fogmeister has promised to add an answer concerning that later, so I won't do that. But I **can** answer the actual question, even though it's not what you *should* do.

From your code I can see that you probably have outlets for all your imageViews (imgView1 ... imgView36) and set each image manually. To detect taps on any of these, you could do something like this:

```
func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let allImageViews = [imageView1, imageView2, .... imageView36]
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapImageView(gesture:)))
    allImageViews.forEach({$0.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)})
}

@objc func didTapImageView(gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    guard let imageView = gesture.view as? UIImageView else { return }

    //Here you can put code that will happen regardless of which imageView was tapped.
    imageView.alpha = 0.0

    //If you need to know exactly which imageView was tapped, you can just check
    if imageView == self.imageView1{
        //Do stuff only for imageView1
    }else if imageView == self.imageView2{
        //...
    }//....
}
```

Again, this is not very good practice. If you go for UICollectionView instead, you don't have to have outlets for all your imageViews and you don't have to create a gestureRecognizer for handling events. But still, I hope this helped you understand general gestures better.

Comment: thanks for your response.. I see where this is heading to.. yeah, i should consider a collectionview haha.. anyway, gonna implement this until I have a better solution. Thank you again.